# 18 06,12,18 * * * what does this mean in cron issue time?

Tags: linux

WHat does the following line mean in Linux - Chrone Time Scheduling

18 06,12,18 * *

Is it it will run 6.18 am, 12.18 pm and 6.18 pm every day for all month of all week.?

Comment: http://crontranslator.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check it out in [manual page for crontab](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5), either online or by typing `man 5 crontab` in terminal.

It means that the command will run at 6:18, 12:18 and 18:18 every day.

Also, I think you're missing one asterix (`*`) - there should be five time and date fields, and you've got only four (although, in post title, you've got five). Anyway, the full definition would look like:

```
18 06,12,18 * * *
```

Answer (score -1):

You can test your cron job on [cron job generator site page.](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcron.nmonitoring.com%2Fcron-generator.html&ei=ekM2U-CeHcPxiAfv_oGoAw&usg=AFQjCNFHyKTFEejJZpBGriNFgRCqSX-QUg&bvm=bv.63808443,d.aGc)
This is very helpful.

Just select whatever options you want for cron job and generate the code.